# Taking the text output when table cell value is blank in python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table

I'm writing a beautifulsoup/python code to scrape data from an html table. the issue with the table is that certain columns may have blank data (cell is empty). when i run this code, the first time it encounters a blank cell in the table, it stops with a "type error", and I get output only till that line of code.

CODE below halts with type error at first occurrence of an empty cell.

```
for tr in rows:
  cols = tr.findAll('td')
  for td in cols:
      text = ''.join(td.find(text=True))
  print
```

sample output of above code -

```
A,  123,  c,  d,  6,  0,  KK, G,
V,  21,  b,  e,  6,  5,  kk, g,
M,  1,  a,  f,  7,  5,  BB,
```

Note that in the last line of above output, there is no data after last value (BB). this is because in the table there is a blank cell, and as a result python stops running after outputting this much.

I tried modifying it, but now it keeps entering blank in certain cells which already had data.

Updated code:

```
for tr in rows:
  cols = tr.findAll('td')
  for td in cols:

      if td.find(text=''):
          text = ''.join('blank')
      else:
          text = ''.join(td.find(text=True))
      print text + ", ",
   print
```

Sample output of above code -

```
blank,  123,  c,  d,  6,  0,  blank, blank,
blank,  21,  b,  e,  6,  5,  blank, blank,
blank,  1,  a,  f,  7,  5,  blank,
```

Note- even in the above it stops after encountering the actual blank data in third cell.

what am I doing wrong? I basically want the cells output to be BLANK when the cell has no data, otherwise the output should be the actual cell content.

Comment: Provide code *and* data that actually show this error in a reproducable way. We must not build our own HTML test data for checking your code.

Comment: @esaelPsnoroMoN - i ve updated with the output.

Comment: I clearly asked for a reproducable code example. Provide a code segment that I can directly copy&paste and run.

Answer (score 1):

The `TypeError` might be caused by `.find_all(text=True)` returning `None`: `''.join(None)` raises `TypeError`. Check that text is not None or empty before `''.join`:

```
import csv
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # pip install beautifulsoup4

csv_writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for tr in soup(id='your_table')('tr', recursive=False):
    row = []
    for td in tr('td', recursive=False):
        text = td(text=True)
        row.append(''.join(text) if text else 'blank')
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```